# RxJava2 compile error "cannot find symbol method body()"

Tags: java, response, retrofit2, rx-java2

I got an compile error in that part of code

```
mCompositeDisposable.add(
            Flowable.just(Boolean.TRUE)
                .flatMap( ignored ->
                        service.getPosts(offset,limit, PreferencesUtils.getAccessTokenKey()) )
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .doOnNext(response -> {
                    if (!response.isSuccessful()) throw new IllegalAccessException();
                })
                .retryWhen( error -> error.flatMap( f -> {
                    if(f instanceof IllegalAccessException)
                        return Helper.refreshToken();
                    else 
                        return Flowable.error(f);
                }))
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(
                        successResponse -> {
                            if (!successResponse.body().isEmpty()) {
                                mView.showNewsFeedItems(successResponse.body());
                            }
                        },
                        failResponse -> { mView.showError(); }
            ));
```

This line of code IDE recognize well and doesn't give any exceptions or warnings
successResponse has type `Response<List<Object>>` but compiler doesn't think as well and give me `error: cannot find symbol method body()` i can't find alike questions & answers how to solve this problem. I will be very grateful for any information about this problem!

`if (!successResponse.body().isEmpty()) {
                                mView.showNewsFeedItems(successResponse.body());
                            }`

Update:

Everything works fine when i use Observer (with Observable), but it's costly

```
 .subscribe(new Observer<Response<List<NewsFeed>>>() { // lambda doesnt work properly here (in progress)
                @Override public void onSubscribe(Disposable s) {}
                @Override public void onNext(Response<List<NewsFeed>> feeds) {if(!feeds.body().isEmpty()) mView.showNewsFeedItems(feeds.body());}
                @Override public void onError(Throwable e) {}
                @Override public void onComplete() {}
            });
```

Comment: How is `getPosts` defined? What compiler version are you using on what platform?

Comment: @akarnokd Observable<Response<List<NewsFeed>>> with 2 '@Query 'and 1 '@Header' in parameters
compileSdkVersion 27

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Single.just() if you guaranty need this emission. It will bring you back Disposable which can be added inside of CompositeDisposable. Subscribe to Flowable returns Subscription, not Disposable.

Comment: thanks for respond. i changed it to flowable a moment ago. at observable works fine when i add (new observer) to subscribe with overriden onComplete, onSubscribe what i don't need, On Flowable i can't use observer and it looks costly 2 empty methods. when i use lambda situation is equivalent

Comment: look at my edited comment and give feedback. If you're talking that with Observable it woks fine then the reason is in your wrong type which you're passing inside of CompositeDisposable. Try to use Single - it's designed to produce only one emission just your case and it returns Disposable

Comment: CompositeDisposable doesn't play important role in this situation, 
Observable works fine when i use 'new Observer<Response<List<NewsFeed>>>() { .. 4 overriden methods, 1 from them is not empty }' in subscribe method.  Observable, Flowable, Single doesn't work when i want to use lamdas, i everytime getting a compile error

Comment: Ok, could you post your Observer realization which worked well? I think it could help us. It sounds a little bit strange. You're saying that you overrided only 1 method in observer, but here in lambda you're passing two arguments for consumer and for error